# Idiom like "catch on fast"

Tags: idioms

I'm looking for idiom like "catch on fast".

How else can you say *a quick learner* and *a short learning curve*?

Comment: The expression "short learning curve" (a derivative of the more common "**steep** learning curve") attaches to the *learning process* associated with acquiring some particular skill, not to the learner himself. To describe the person, you've already got what's idiomatically the most common usage by far - ***quick learner***. Stick with it.

Comment: ***quick learner*** or ***quick study*** are both very common.

Comment: a fast learner is someone who can easily master a new concept with the minimum time compared to others of the same age.

Comment: See also: [What is a word in English that means “able to learn new things quickly”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/23014/11482). Personally, I like *receptive* and *sponge*, but they aren't idioms. For an idiom, [bright as a button](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bright) could work.

Answer (score 3):

**Quick/fast learner** is the most appropriate term you can convey the message without any ambiguity.

Nevertheless, *apt pupil*, *sharp*, *quick-witted* etc. are quite close to the term. Another term (a single word) close to it is -

> [Clever (adj)](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/clever) - quick at learning and understanding things.

However, the above word is quite common in BrE to describe someone with a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is **quick on the uptake**. Alternatively, a quick learner can be described as **sharp** "Don't worry about her getting overwhelmed by her new job - she's sharp."

Answer (score 0):

For sponge one could say....Soaks up information like a sponge!